# 404 on new install of Glassfish

Tags: glassfish

I am ***BRAND NEW*** to Glassfish, so I thought I would install a copy and poke around (I'm actually looking at a number of Java servers for personal edification).  So, I installed a basic copy of Glassfish 3 on Ubuntu 10 and java-6-openjdk.

My first run through, I tried using sudo ./glassfish-3.0.1-unix.sh.  Unfortunately, when I called ./asadmin start-domain and then navigated to the admin panel (at the default location), I found only this (there is more HTML on the page, but this is the only *text*.  I can provide the entire HTML doc if needed.):

```
<div id="copyright" style="width: 720px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; padding: 5px;"> 
        <span>Copyright © 2005, 2010, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.  U.S. Government Rights - Commercial software. Government users are subject to the Oracle standard license agreement and applicable provisions of the FAR and its supplements. Use is subject to license terms. This distribution may include materials developed by third parties. Portions may be derived from Berkeley BSD systems, licensed from U. of CA. Oracle, Java and GlassFish are registered trademarks of Oracle and/or its affiliates.</span> 
    </div>
```

Also, the form with the ID "loginButton" is clearly missing from the HTML.

So, I uninstalled that version of Glassfish and installed using sudo ./glassfish-3.0.1-web-unix.sh.  This had the same error.  Finally, I tried installing it without using sudo, but I ran into the same error.

How do I get the stupid admin page working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried it with the real version of java rather than openjdk?